# How To: Localization System.ComponentModel.Design.CollectionEditor.CollectionForm for PropertyGrid

Tags: c#, .net, propertygrid

I'm using standard PropertyGrid in my Windows Forms project. But CollectionEditor.CollectionForm what is used for edit collections always in English: buttons, labels and error messages. How I can change culture for this dialog for Russian (ru-RU)?

Answer (score 0):

The culture is based on a thread. So if you dont see it, you probably do not have Russian language support installed.